# Переход на указанный в форме URL

Tags: url, javascript, форма

Помогите реализовать (дописать), не совсем понимаю но вроде всё просто...

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Скрыть 
function test1(form) {
  if (form.url.value == "")
    alert("Введите адрес сайта!")
  else { 
   document.location.href = "http://www.site.ru";
  }
}
// -->
</script>

<form name="first">
<input type="text" name="url">
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Перейти" onClick="test1(this.form)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы хотели так:

```
if($('form').find('input[name=url]').val() == '')
...
else
...
```